# Download Visual Studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it possible to download full visual studio code instead of using the web instaler of the official page?
I want several users to do the installation simultaneously and I want to avoid that everyone makes a simultaneous download of the same product.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this direct link
https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?Linkid=852157
assuming you are using Windows 64bit